# Count of files in C# with LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

**Env**: C#, VStudio 2013, 4.5 Framework, Winforms

**Goal** : Getting the number of files (Count) in a folder and subfolder that match extensions stored in an array of string. The array of extension can be with the "." of not. {".dat","txt",".msg"}

**What i've done so far** : When I'm having the "." in the array of extensions, everything is working : {".dat",".txt",".msg"}

I have tried the Replace but it's always returning 0.

The working code (Only if always with the "." in array of string):

```
string[] ext= new string[] { ".txt", ".msg", ".dat" };
totalFilesInTN = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dlg1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                          .Count(s => ext.Any(s1 => s1 == Path.GetExtension(s)));
```

The not working code (always return 0) :

```
string[] ext= new string[] { "txt", ".msg", "dat" };
totalFilesInTN = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dlg1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                          .Count(s => ext.Any(s1 => s1 == Path.GetExtension(s).Replace(".", "")));
```

Comment: Try where clause first then do the count.

Comment: @Nazmul: that's basically the same as using no `Where` but a predicate in `Count`.

Comment: I know that let try it and see anything change on it. Sometime this LINQ fail to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for the [`Path.GetExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method states that the return value is:

> The extension of the specified path (including the period "."), or null, or String.Empty.

Your second block of code strips off the '.' so none of the elements will match.  Therefore, go the opposite way with your list of extensions and just ensure that the start of each extension has a '.' and then use your first block of code.

```
string[] ext = new string[] {"txt", ".msg", ".dat" }
    .Select(x => x.StartsWith(".") ? x : "." + x)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: The `using System.Linq` hint is redundant since OP is already using LINQ, apart from that +1

Comment: Good point.  It's still early for details like that :) but I like to make things clear for future readers.

Comment: I don't want to nitpick but if it's going to be accepted it might also worth noting why OP's second approach doesn't work. Because the removes the dot from the `Path.GetExtension` value but not from  his array-extension.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the `.` dot in both the array `ext` element and the directory item. You need to use .Replace with `s1` as well to compare the array and file extension after removing dot from each.

```
string[] ext= new string[] { "txt", ".msg", "dat" };
totalFilesInTN = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dlg1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                 .Count(s => ext.Any(s1 => s1.Replace(".", "") == Path.GetExtension(s).Replace(".", "")));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you have to remove the dots from both extensions. The `Path.GetExtension` always prepends the dot. But it's you extension  array that can contain   extensions without. So you have to remove the dot from both if you want to compare them:

So instead of

```
....Count(s => ext.Any(s1 => s1 == Path.GetExtension(s).Replace(".", "")));
```

this:

```
....Count(s => ext.Any(s1 => si.Replace(".", "") == Path.GetExtension(s).Replace(".", "")));
```

But as others have mentioned, fix the invalid source, modify the array that it only contains extensions with dot. Then it's much more readable and efficient.

You can also use `Contains`:

```
....Count(s => ext.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Then GetExtension() method always includes the ".", so you have to normalize the extension that you are checking.

```
string[] extensions = new string[] { "docx", ".msg", "pdf" };
var filesCount = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
 .Count(filePath => extensions.Any(e => (e.StartsWith(".") ? e : "." + e) == Path.GetExtension(filePath)));
```

But it's better normalize the collection only once at the beginning.